# Error when changing font in Quarto/tinytex

Tags: fonts, latex, quarto, tinytex, fontspec

I have a Quarto document I would like to create a pdf with using tinytex. I would like to use two different fonts at different points in the document, and so I'm using `\setmainfont{font-name}` at various points in the document. All the fonts I'm trying to use have definitely been installed on my machine---in fact, I can verify this by running

`systemfonts::system_fonts()`

in R and I can see both the fonts I want in the data frame that's returned. I'm getting an error when I try to use one of the fonts but not the other. Any explanation for why?

Here's a more specific example. The two fonts I want to use are called "Alegreya" and "Domestic Manners." They have both been installed on my computer. The following document knits just fine:

```
---
format: pdf
---

This is in "normal" font.

\setmainfont{Alegreya}
This is in "Alegreya" font.
```

But this one gives me "Package fontspec Error: The font "Domestic Manners" cannot be found."

```
---
format: pdf
---

This is in "normal" font.

\setmainfont{Domestic Manners}
This is in "Domestic Manners" font.
```

Note that if I do it in HTML and use something like `<span style="font-family: Domestic Manners">` it works! This makes me think it's a tinytex thing but I can't figure out how to convince tinytex to install this other font!

Thanks very much =)

Comment: Can you a) try to compile with lualatex instead of xelatex b) add which operating system you are using